# Can I bind some macro-postprocessing to an Emacs abbreviation?

Tags: emacs, macros, abbreviation

I'm trying to create "smart" abbreviations that expand to some text and then move the cursor. E.g., in C mode I'd like `INC` to expand to `#include <>` with the cursor between the <> signs. Or, in HTML mode: `BF` expanded to `<b></b>` with the cursor at the right spot.

What's a smart way of going about this (short of defining functions for all this and binding them to a key, which I don't want to do, because I'd prefer abbreviations)?

Comment: Try https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet

Comment: FYI in 2020 yasnippet has a new home https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet

Answer (score 2):

I would heartily recommend Yasnippets. It seems to be designed to do exactly what you want.

- [EmacsWiki: Yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet)
- [ErgoEmacs summary of Yasnippet](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_templates.html)
- [Yasnippet on GitHub](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet)

You can install it through Elpa as well.

Comment: Yasnippet is definitely a favorite of mine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this:

> hippie-expand is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `hippie-exp.el'. It is bound to M-pause. (hippie-expand arg)
>
> Try to expand text before point, using multiple methods. The expansion
>   functions in `hippie-expand-try-functions-list' are tried in order,
>   until a possible expansion is found.  Repeated application of`
>   hippie-expand' inserts successively possible expansions. With a
>   positive numeric argument, jumps directly to the arg next function in
>   this list.  With a negative argument or just C-u, undoes the
>   expansion.
>
> [back]

It is bound to M-pause on my system, probably not on yours yet.

Answer (score 0):

Define abbrev. Than

<kbd>M-x</kbd> edit-abbrevs <kbd>RET</kbd>

Fourth slot receives a function. For example write:

```
(lambda nil (forward-char -1))
```

in order to move backwards one char after expansion.